# Highchart contextmenu export black screen when stylemode

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using [Highcharts the latest version v9.2.1](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js). In without stylemode I can successfully export using the chart's context menu.
However, when I try to use HighCharts in "Styled Mode," all of these options export an all-black image. I have correctly included "highcharts/css/highcharts.css" in my code and the charts are rendering correctly.
http://jsfiddle.net/ringkubd/5n1am372/7/

```js
$(function() {

  // Create the chart
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    lang: {
      printChart: 'Skriv ut diagram',
      downloadPNG: 'Ladda ner PNG',
      downloadJPEG: 'Ladda ner JPEG',
      downloadPDF: 'Ladda ner PDF',
      downloadSVG: 'Ladda ner SVG',
      contextButtonTitle: 'Innehålls meny'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      styledMode: true
    },

    title: {
      text: 'ADL'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'Hygien',
        'Tandborstning',
        'Klädsel, efter aktivitet och årstid',
        'Tidspassning',
        'Hushålla med egen ekonomi',
        'Uppträdande vid matbordet',
        'Uppträdande i sällskapsrummen',
        'Uppträdande vid aktivitet',
        'Städning av bostadsrummet',
        'Prylordning',
        'Klädvård',
      ],
      crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: [{
        max: 4,
        tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        className: 'highcharts-color-0',
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
      },
      {
        className: 'highcharts-color-1',
        opposite: true,
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
      }
    ],

    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        borderRadius: 5
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: "Personal skattar",
      data: [4.0000,
        3.3333,
        2.0000,
        4.0000,
        4.0000,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
      ]
    }, {
      name: "Klient skattar",
      data: [2.0000,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
      ],
    }]
  });

});
```

```css
 @import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

 /* Link the series colors to axis colors */
 .highcharts-color-0 {
   fill: #FF9933;
   stroke: #FF9933;
 }

 .highcharts-axis.highcharts-color-0 .highcharts-axis-line {
   stroke: #FF9933;
 }

 .highcharts-axis.highcharts-color-0 text {
   fill: #FF9933;
 }

 .highcharts-color-1 {
   fill: #91C400;
   stroke: #91C400;
 }

 .highcharts-axis.highcharts-color-1 .highcharts-axis-line {
   stroke: #91C400;
 }

 .highcharts-axis.highcharts-color-1 text {
   fill: #91C400;
 }

 .highcharts-yaxis .highcharts-axis-line {
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```

et/ringkubd/5n1am372/7/>.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like regression, I reported it on Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16231

Try to use the last working version: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6qhgfLk4/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/9.1.2/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/9.1.2/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```